# YTD for the below query

Tags: sql, teradata

I want to add add the Year to date component to this code. I have tried some other ways but I am not getting what I would like to see. Can someone please help me revised this to include the YTD in addition to the Month to date that is already there?

```
SELECT
    COST__DESC,
    ST.AD_SRV_MTN AS MONTH_OF_AD,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CM.CM_NBR) AS CMS,
    MEM_MO AS MBR_MTH,
    CMS/MBR_MTH*1000 AS CMS_PER_1000
FROM XTR.FT_CM AS CM
JOIN XTR.FT_ST AS ST ON ST.CM_NBR = CM.CM_NBR
JOIN XTR.DIM_MED_CST AS MC ON ST.CST_CK = MCC.CST_CK
JOIN XTR.DIM_AF AS AFF ON ST.PRO_CK = AFF.AFF_CK
JOIN XTR.DIM_ADJDCTN_STAT AS A_S ON ST.ADJDCTN_STAT_CK = A_S.ADJDCTN_STAT_CK
JOIN XTR.DIM_ADJ_OT AS OT ON ST.ADJ_CK = OT.ADJ_CK
LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT
            CALENDAR_YEAR_MONTH as YEAR_MO,
            SUM(MBR.COUNT_NBR) as MEM_MO
        FROM XTR.FT_MBR_MONTHS MBR
        INNER JOIN DIM_MBR_C ON MBR.DB_MBR_CK = DIM_MBR_C.DB_MBR_CK
                                AND MBR.DATE_CK BETWEEN DIM_MBR_C.DB_eff_date_ck
                                AND DIM_MBR_C.DB_END_DATE_CK
        INNER JOIN DIM_DATE DT ON ELI_DATE_CK = DT.DATE_CK
        WHERE MBR.F_C_CK = 500058321 AND YEAR_MO >= 201701
        GROUP BY 1) MM ON ST.AD_SRV_MTN = MM.YEAR_MO
WHERE ST.F_C_CK = 500058321 AND ST.ST_START_DATE_CK >= 20200101
      AND ST.AD_SRV_MTN > 201912 AND MC.MED_DESC IN ('Er', 'IP')
      AND ST.AD_SRV_MTN < ((EXTRACT (YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) *100) + 
                           EXTRACT (MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE))
GROUP BY 1,2,4
ORDER BY 1,2
```

Comment: esentially I want to add YTD_CMS; YTD_MBR_MTH, YTD_CMS_PER_1000

Comment: This SQL is very complex.  We would need table structures and sample data to assist you with this.  There is also a join 'JOIN XTR.DIM_DED_CST AS MC ON ST.CST_CK = MCC.CST_CK' that doesn't make sense and should error as the alias MC is not correctly linked to any tables.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I don't really get your SQL and what is counted, but: Your can play with dates quite easy in Teradata, as Dates are stored (and can be used) internally as INTEGER. Just keep in mind year 1900 as year 0 and format YYYYMMDD.
So e.g. 16-Apr-2020 is in Format YYYYMMDD 20200416 and if you take 1900 as 0 you'll end up with 1200416 which is the internal format. Just try `SELECT CURRENT_DATE (INT);` - So if you want compare YearNumers you just have to divide by 10000.

With this your can implement YTD as `SUM (CASE WHEN CURRENT_DATE/10000 = <YourDateField>/10000 THEN <YourKPI> else 0 END) as YourKPI_YTD`. Counting can be done by `SUM...THEN 1 ELSE 0 END...`.